# Capybara holds only one authorized request, all others return 401

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, testing, rspec

My problem is that capybara holds only one authorized request (doesn't matter was it authorization through the login form or through the helper `login_as` method) 
Other (second, third) requests are unauthorized!
It doesn't mater what driver I use. Where the problem can be?

```
# This file is copied to spec/ when you run 'rails generate rspec:install'
ENV['RAILS_ENV'] ||= 'test'
require File.expand_path('../../config/environment', __FILE__)
# Prevent database truncation if the environment is production
abort('The Rails environment is running in production mode!') if Rails.env.production?
require 'spec_helper'
require 'rspec/rails'
require 'capybara/rspec'
require 'capybara/poltergeist'

# NOTE: For Chrome support
Capybara.register_driver :selenium do |app|
  Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, :browser => :chrome)
end

# Capybara.register_driver(:poltergeist) { |app| Capybara::Poltergeist::Driver.new(app, js_errors: false) }
# Capybara.javascript_driver = :poltergeist

Dir[Rails.root.join('spec/support/**/*.rb')].each { |f| require f }

# Checks for pending migration and applies them before tests are run.
# If you are not using ActiveRecord, you can remove this line.
ActiveRecord::Migration.maintain_test_schema!

RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include FactoryGirl::Syntax::Methods
  config.include WaitForAjax
  config.include FeatureHelpers
  config.include Devise::TestHelpers, type: :controller
  config.include Warden::Test::Helpers
  config.extend ControllerHelpers,    type: :controller

  # Remove this line if you're not using ActiveRecord or ActiveRecord fixtures
  config.fixture_path = "#{::Rails.root}/spec/fixtures"

  # If you're not using ActiveRecord, or you'd prefer not to run each of your
  # examples within a transaction, remove the following line or assign false
  # instead of true.
  config.use_transactional_fixtures = false

  # RSpec Rails can automatically mix in different behaviours to your tests
  # based on their file location, for example enabling you to call `get` and
  # `post` in specs under `spec/controllers`.
  #
  # You can disable this behaviour by removing the line below, and instead
  # explicitly tag your specs with their type, e.g.:
  #
  #     RSpec.describe UsersController, :type => :controller do
  #       # ...
  #     end
  #
  # The different available types are documented in the features, such as in
  # https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs
  config.infer_spec_type_from_file_location!

  # Filter lines from Rails gems in backtraces.
  config.filter_rails_from_backtrace!
  # arbitrary gems may also be filtered via:
  # config.filter_gems_from_backtrace("gem name")
  config.before :suite do
    Warden.test_mode!
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Most probably between the first request and the second, rspec cleans up the DB.

For this second request the user form the first request no more exists. You should create another user and login/authorize it.

Ex:

For each `it` block you'll have to do a `login_as(a_new_just_created_user)`. Yes, you can put this into a `before` block to be executed for the entire test suite.

```
describe '' do
  before do
    login_as(a_new_just_created_user)
  end

  context '' do
    it '' { get 'api/url' } # first user logged in
    it '' { get 'api/url' } # second user logged in
  end

  context '' do
    it '' { get 'api/url' } # third user logged in
  end
end
```

Comment: Thank you for answer. But..
I must perform `login_as` not before each block, but even before each action! Ex: 
login_as user
visit user_edit_path
login_as user
visit user_comments_path;